# JSX Style React Native Components With Children

Tags: typescript, react-native

I've done some research on this, but all of the examples I've found are convoluted. I'm trying to boil this down to its most basic elements. I've also not found an example of the style I'm looking for. But I'm wondering if I'm able to create custom React Native components with children components in this style:

```js
function CompositeComponent(): ReactElement {

  return (
    <CustomParentComponent>
      // ✅ I would like to add child elements in the normal XML style.
      <CustomChildComponent />
    </CustomParentComponent>
  );
}
```

So far, this is the only way I've found how to do child elements in custom components:

```js
function CompositeComponent(): ReactElement {

  return (
    // ❌ I'd like to avoid creating child elements in this style, if possible.
    <CustomParentComponent childComponent={<CustomChildComponent />}>
    </CustomParentComponent>
  );
}
```

This is done all the time with the standard React Native components such as `View` and `Text`, but I can't seem to find any examples with custom components.

What would my `CustomParentComponent` definition need to look like to accomplish this?

Edit -

I've tried this:

```js
function CustomParentComponent(child: ReactElement): ReactElement {

  return (
    <CustomParentComponent>
      {child}
    </CustomParentComponent>
  );
}
```

But this doesn't work when I try to add the `CustomChildComponent` in the JSX/XML style:

```js
function CompositeComponent(): ReactElement {

  return (
    <CustomParentComponent>
      // ❌Error❌ Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>': type, props, keyts(2739)
      <CustomChildComponent />
    </CustomParentComponent>
  );
}
```

Comment: Whats confusing you? You just have to pass children as you have done in the first code snippet. In your `CustomParentComponent`, you will receive it inside your children props. smiply render the `children` props in `CustomParentComponent`.

Comment: I'll edit my answer with what I've tried. I'd hoped to leave it more open-ended because I didn't want to get too caught up in a specific error but, rather, keep the discussion on a definition for the `CustomParentComponent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your `CustomParentComponent` to receive the children props and then you just have to render the `children`.

For example, consider the below code,

```js
const CustomParentComponent = (props) => (
  <View>
    {props.children}
  </View>
);
```

Now you can pass your children components to your `CustomParentComponent` by

```js
<CustomParentComponent>
  <CustomChildComponent />
</CustomParentComponent>
```

Remember `children` is more of a default props in `React`. You can verify this by simply printing out the virtual dom tree.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Hadn't ever seen that! Just for the sake of noting it, I also wanted to mention that I had to type the `children` property as a `React.ReactNode`.